# Query System Views From Linked Server - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, linked-server

I'm tasked with creating a report that will pull down the permissions from different servers and display them.

I'm having an issue with the query not picking up all of the rows in from the system view, from another server.

When I run the below query on `serverA`, it gives me `251` results.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ServerA.employee.sys.objects
```

When I run the same code from `ServerB`, I get `153` results.

I compared the two and it looks like the linked server isn't pulling `type_desc` of `SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION`, `SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE`, and `SYSTEM_TABLE`.

Does anyone know way I can get a list of database object permissions running from a different server in SQL server?

Comment: Are you using SSRS for the report?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SSRS for the report, you can setup a dynamic data source to run the same report for multiple servers/databases. I'd use a static data source at first to setup the datasets, otherwise the columns will not get created automatically.

```
="Data Source=" & Parameters!ServerName.Value & ";Initial Catalog=" & Parameters!DatabaseName.Value
```

Here is the listing of permissions on schema objects within a database.

```
SELECT 
      pr.principal_id
    , pr.name
    , pr.type_desc
    , pr.authentication_type_desc
    , pe.state_desc
    , pe.permission_name
    , ObjectName = s.name + '.' + o.name  
FROM 
    sys.database_principals AS pr  
    INNER JOIN sys.database_permissions AS pe ON pe.grantee_principal_id = pr.principal_id  
    INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o ON pe.major_id = o.object_id  
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id;
```

[Microsoft Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-database-permissions-transact-sql)